# CiviMail adding ?civiwp=CiviCRM to all links - causing links to be bad

Tags: wordpress, civimail, mosaico

Using Mosaico 2.3 (2.4 does not work for us) & traditional civimail.
CiviCRM 5.27.1 WordPress 5.4.2

All url's in civimail append ?civiwp=CiviCRM - causing errors when linking to wordpress pages. example.org becomes example.org/?civiwp=CiviCRM - This is fine for most URLs but causes issues with wordpress urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  That is a bug.  here is the report - https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1865

It's been fixed https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/bcbfa93e255ee15d9bd9e0f812b2a5a617458d73  and is planned for the next 5.27 release

Comment: That fixed it - thank you!